# Convert numpy ndarray to tuple of tuples in optimize method

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy ndarray, result of opencv findContours().
I want to convert each element of the result from numpy array to tuple of tuples efficiently.
Tried tolist(), asarray() etc but none of them give me the exact result.

**example**

numpy array:

```
    [[[191 307]]

     [[190 308]]

     [[181 308]]]
```

to tuple of tuples:

```
((191,307),(190,308),(181,308))
```

**update**
`tuple(elements[0])`   return

```
(array([[191 ,307]], dtype=int32),array([[190, 308]], dtype=int32),array([[181,308]], dtype=int32))
```

Comment: list of tuples or tuple of tuples?

Comment: Im not sure.  
assume I write this line x=((0,0),(1,1)).  
 x is list of tuples right? @MatinaG

Comment: try `my_list = numpy.ndarray.tolist(my_array)` first and then `tuple(my_list)`

Comment: sorry, this is a tuple of tuples

Comment: How about `tuple(tuple(ai) for ai in my_array)`?

Comment: I added the output I got from your code. @JonasAdler

Comment: @mamad this is not working, it kinda tuple of list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [9]: a = numpy.array([[[191, 307]],
   ...:                  [[190, 308]],
   ...:                  [[181, 308]]])

In [10]: tuple(tuple(row[0]) for row in a)
Out[10]: ((191, 307), (190, 308), (181, 308))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is 3d:

```
In [356]: a.shape
Out[356]: (3, 1, 2)
```

If you remove the middle dimension, it's easy to iterate on the rest:

```
In [357]: tuple(tuple(i) for i in a[:,0,:])
Out[357]: ((191, 307), (190, 308), (181, 308))
```

If it doesn't have to be tuples, `tolist` is enough:

```
In [358]: a[:,0,:].tolist()
Out[358]: [[191, 307], [190, 308], [181, 308]]
```

Comment: I've just asked [Convert any multi-dimensional numpy array to tuple of tuples of tuples… agnostic of number of dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68361779/3904031)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the question is about converting nested `numpy.array` to nested `tuple`s by unpacking single-element subarrays (`[1]` => `1`, or `[[1, 2]]` => `[1, 2]`). I apply a recursive function to do such a conversion in the following, which can be generalized to any **sized iterable containers**. All 4 inputs generate the same expected output: `res = ((191, 307), (190, 308), (181, 308))`.

[`collections.abc.Collection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) ensures that the container has the following methods `__contains__`, `__iter__`, `__len__`.

```py
from collections.abc import Collection
import numpy as np

# npArr = np.array([[[191], [307]], [[190], [308]], [[181], [308]]])
npArr = np.array([[[191, 307]], [[190, 308]], [[181, 308]]])
# npArr = np.array([[[191, 307], [190, 308], [181, 308]]])
# npArr = np.array([[191, 307], [190, 308], [181, 308]])

def func(val):
    if not isinstance(val, Collection):
        return val
    
    if len(val) == 1:
        return func(val[0])

    return tuple(func(elem) for elem in val)

res = func(npArr)
print(f"{npArr = }")
print(f"{res = }")
```