# Convert any multi-dimensional numpy array to tuple of tuples of tuples... agnostic of number of dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

That [this answer to *Convert numpy ndarray to tuple of tuples in optimize method*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51882108/3904031) doens't offer anything more than `tuple(tuple(i) for i in a[:,0,:])` suggests this doesn't exist, but I am looking for something like a `.totuple()` method similar to numpy's `.tolist()` in that *you don't need to know the number of dimensions beforehand* to generate a tuple of tuples of tuples...

For my needs this would apply to a float or integer numerical array only.

Comment: ``numpy` does not have hidden methods!  For most purposes `tolists` is sufficient, and faster than any iteration on an array.  It also takes the conversion all the way down, producing python end values (i.e. `int` instead of `np.int64`).

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, I have a hunch that JelleWestra's answer is as good as it's going to get. I'll see if I can make `.tolist()` work for me. If there's no `totupple()` there must be some reason for that. Is there a PEP for [I Do Not Want What I Haven't Got](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Do_Not_Want_What_I_Haven%27t_Got)? :-)

Comment: @uhoh You could submit this as a feature request to [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues).

Comment: @user76284 after seeing your nice answer I thought about it, but 1) an n-nested tuple is a weird thing, it would then want a shape method of its own (I had to print b[0][0][0][0] to see if b = totuple(np.arange(2**5).reshape(*5*[2])) worked). Usually feature requests need to make a good case for a real need; "What problems/challenges does it solve?" I wouldn't know how to argue such a thing.

Comment: @uhoh One common use case is getting a hashable and immutable representation of an array, e.g. to store in a set or as a key in a dictionary. (In this respect, it's more useful than tolist.) There are many questions on SO about converting an array to a nested tuple. These could perhaps be used as examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more explicit alternative:

```py
def totuple(a):
    if a.shape == ():
        return a.item()
    else:
        return tuple(map(totuple, a))
```

Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(3 * 4).reshape(3, 4)
print(totuple(a))
```

```
((0, 1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6, 7), (8, 9, 10, 11))
```

Comment: Nice! [Zen of Python 'Explicit is better than implicit'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64070128/3904031)

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a recursive function which converts to a tuple independent of the number of dimensions:

```
def totuple(a):
    try:
        return tuple(totuple(i) for i in a)
    except TypeError:
        return a
```

Found in this answer:
[Convert numpy array to tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016352/convert-numpy-array-to-tuple)

Comment: Interesting! I will give it a try. I was hoping for "something like a `.totuple()` *method* similar to numpy's `.tolist()`" so I wouldn't have to rewrite it every time I need it, but it may not exist.

Comment: @uhoh As far as I'm aware, there doesn't exist such a method or function in numpy unfortunately.

Comment: Applying this function to the `tolist` result is probably faster.